# NOT operator in GMP for C++

Tags: c++, gmp

Is there any way to negate every bit of a `mpz_class` variable in C++ e.g finding its bitwise complement? I'm looking for something like

```
mpz_class num = 0b1110101;
num = ~num; // num should now be 0b0001010
```

but using `~num` returns `(-1) * num - 1` and the `cmp` function doesn't really work as it doesn't change any of the values of the parameters and it just returns `1` or `-1`.

Comment: I'm not familiar with GMP, but its behavior makes sense. The first number is essentially `00...001110101`. If you want it to be `11...110101` instead, it should be negative.

Comment: How does the result of `~num` differ from negating every bit in the underlying value?

Comment: I'm wondering if you want arbitrarily large numbers or just bit vectors of a fixed length. What is it you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt probably bit vectors of a fixed length, as those would probably achieve the result I'm trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

Something like this does what you said

```
num = ((mpz_class(1) << mpz_sizeinbase(num.get_mpz_t(), 2)) - 1 - num);
```

But if you are looking for an absolute fixed length, then instead

```
num = ((mpz_class(1) << LENGTH) - 1 - num);
```

for some suitable value of `LENGTH`. Of course if you have a fixed length then `(mpz_class(1) << LENGTH) - 1` is a constant and can be precalculated.